# Windows 7 Icons Corrupted

Tags: windows-7, icons

All of a sudden my Windows 7 Icons are not showing the correct logo. They all look corrupted. I have tried clearing iconcache and restarting the computer. Nothing worked. Is there anything else that I can try?

[image: ScreenPrint]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Check if your default application has been changed for that type of files.

Comment: Yes that's the first thing I verified

Comment: Are those shortcuts? If so, what does the `.lnk` actually contain?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the icons cache located at `%LocalAppData%\IconCache.db`.

If that didn't work, there are possibilities.

- The registry (`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`) has some registry keys (possibly `DefaultIcon`) deleted or corrupted.
- The icons' location (`.ico`, `.exe` or `.dll`) is deleted or corrupted.

### If issues comes from third-party software

Try to reinstall (uninstall and install again) the software, doing that will recreate the missing files and/or registry keys.

### If issues comes from Windows software

It depends, if you know what DLLs or EXEs are deleted/corrupted you can download them, for example, download the DLLs from dll-files.com

If you don't know where's the issue, try to find the corrupted/missing files. If you still don't know where's the issue and/or you don't know how to fix, you are out of luck, you'll have to format your PC and reinstall Windows.

Comment: None of the above worked.

Comment: What are the extensions of the files shown in your screenshot?

Comment: Xlsx, docx, PDF

Comment: try to reinstall Microsoft Office (Xlsx, docx) and Adobe Reader/Acrobat Pro (PDF), uninstalling and doing a clean install will possibly solve your issue.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately this a corporate laptop. I might have to ask my team to help me with it . I think that will be the last or may be that is the only solution.?

Comment: Corrupted icons can be caused by corrupted/deleted icon container files (like EXE or DLL, or the ICO files itself) and/or wrong registry keys (`DefaultIcon` key manages the file's icon). Reinstalling is the best solution.